# UpdateData function in Cloud Pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, cloudpage

I was trying to update a data extension with suscriber data about interests, I recently added 2 new rows, as this is filled with records from a register form, I'm planning to send an email with a small description and a button with an CloudPage URL.

The landing page is contains a pre populated form with the data I already have. I just want to obtain the interest info for this I'm using select labels.

This is an URL example : https://cloud.mailgranplan.com/actualizar-intereses?qs=c432442b25e5d77d1373366298a3e29cdf36d30cd7b7b6a9f6563174bc418d845036de5070797a8533e3b5d520732d1edfb50363a173c28faf77cc012e38b4faa4278c5c55f2a5ef3bf9bfa46ccb878e08859f8e9ae1d82d

The AMPScript within the landing page is the following:

```
<!-- starts -->

<script runat="server" language="ampscript">

var @emailAddress, @firstName, @lastName, @interes_1, @interes_2

set @success = true

set @emailAddress = AttributeValue("Email")
set @firstName = AttributeValue("Nombre")            
set @lastName = AttributeValue("Apellido")                         
set @interes_1 = AttributeValue("Interes")
set @interes_2 = AttributeValue("Interes_2")

set @updatedDate = Now(1)

if Empty(@interes_1) or Empty(@interes_2) then
  set @success = false
else 
  UpdateData("Formulario Web",1,"Email", @emailAddress, "Interes", @interes_1, "Interes_2",@interes_2, "Updated", @updatedDate)
endif

</script> 

<!-- end -->
```

Someone could help me to know if Im in the right way or what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what error you getting post here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fernando Madrid try like this and remove space with in Data Extension Name
i mean you are trying to get form values right ?

%%[

```
var @emailAddress, @firstName, @lastName, @interes_1, @interes_2

set @success = true

set @emailAddress = RequestParameter('Email')


 set @firstName =RequestParameter('Nombre') 

set @lastName =RequestParameter('Apellido')

 set @interes_1 =RequestParameter('Interes')

 set @interes_2 =RequestParameter('Interes_2')


 set @updatedDate = Now(1)

  if Empty(@interes_1) or Empty(@interes_2) then
    set @success = false
    else 
  UpdateData("FormularioWeb",1,"Email", @emailAddress, "Interes", @interes_1, 
  "Interes_2",@interes_2, "Updated", @updatedDate)
  endif

   ]%%
```

Comment: Hi @pkharries, thanks . I just want to get form values to "interes" and "Interes_2", I want to keep it simple for the users. I tried with your suggestion but It takes me to a bad request page too, https://cloud.mailgranplan.com/False , I think could be the logic in the function but I'm still a beginner in the subject